# Complement and open set on topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Question:
>   Let $Y=\left [ -1,1 \right ]$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ so the subspace property holds.
>   Is $\left \{ x:\frac{1}{2}\leq \left | x \right |<1 \right \}$ an open set?

From the definition of complement,

On a metric space, a proper subset V of X is an open set wrt X if its complement $X\setminus V=\left \{ x \in X : x \notin V \right \}$

Here, $Y\setminus A=\left \{ y \in Y | y \notin A \right \}=\left ( \frac{-1}{2},\frac{1}{2} \right )\cup \left \{ -1 \right \}\cup \left \{ 1 \right \}$

Now, to speak about an open set we have to talk about open balls. I do not have good exposure to elementary real analysis so I'm not exactly sure how can we speak about open ball in this question.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Let $\bar{y}$ be an element in the complement $Y\setminus A=\left ( -1,\frac{-1}{2} \right ] \cup [\frac{1}{2},1 )$
The pertinent is this:

Is there any element $\bar{y} \in Y\setminus A$ st $d\left ( \bar{y},y \right )<\epsilon$
but $B_{\epsilon}\left ( \bar{y} \right )\nsubseteq Y\setminus A$?

Comment: You mean $Y$ is a *subset* rather than a *subspace*, don't you?

Comment: Changes made to OP

Comment: I don't understand the solution by the poster below. I've made an edit to the OP. Would someone assist me?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you say you are operating in a metric space $(\mathbb R,d(x,y))$ and further you're given the subset $$\left \{ x:\frac{1}{2}\leq \left | x \right |<1 \right \}=(-1,-\frac 1 2]\cup[\frac1 2,1)=:X\subset Y\subset \mathbb R$$
A set is called an *open set* if for any point $x\in X$ there exists an $\varepsilon>0$ such that for any given point $y\in Y (\text{or }\mathbb R)$ with $d(x,y)<\varepsilon$, $y$ also belongs to $X$.

Now let's take for example $\displaystyle\frac 1 2\in X$ and any $\varepsilon>0$, then 
$$
\left\{y:y\in Y, d(\frac 1 2,y)<\varepsilon\right\}\not\subset X
$$ 
and therefore your set $X$ cannot be an *open set* in $Y$ (or especially in $\mathbb R$ for this matter).

Comment: I don't understand. You want to show that every element in the complement satisfies the open set definition and the arrive at a conclusion. Why you taking an element in X?. All you're really doing is to show whether or not X is an open set

Comment: I show that there is a point in $X$, $\frac 12$ for which there exists no neighborhood $d(\frac 12,y)$ which is a subset of $X$ - this means, that $X$ is not open. Alternatively you could also show, that the complement is not closed, which I guess was your first idea to do?

Comment: What is that second bracket? Is it an open ball the set of elements in Y?

Comment: What second bracket do you mean?

Comment: The second expression

Comment: Yes, $\left\{y:y\in Y, d(\frac 1 2,y)<\varepsilon\right\}$ is an open ball contained in $Y$ and since there exists no $\varepsilon>0$ such that ball is contained in $X$, the set $X$ is not open.

Comment: Can you explain why there exists no $\epsilon$>0?

Comment: Sorry, your proof is not very intuitive nor understand. I believe this question should be straight forward. If I pick an element in the complement set with epsilon >0, if the ball containing the complement is not contained in the complement set, then the set is closed. Done.

Comment: *Why there exists no $\varepsilon>0$*: if the open ball $\left\{y:y\in Y, d(\frac 1 2,y)<\varepsilon\right\}$ would be contained in $X:=[\frac 12,1)$ this would mean that $(\frac12-\varepsilon,\frac12+\varepsilon)$ would be contained in $[\frac12,1)$, which is clearly not the case for any $\varepsilon>0$. As I said, you could also prove that the complement of $X$ is not closed, this is equivalent. So you basically have to show, that $(-1/2,1/2)$ is not closed (it is indeed open).

Comment: Your use of the open ball notation is really confusing. The open ball in your solution should be the set of all x in X such that the distance between two element in X is less than epsilon. And if I can prove this open ball is not a subset of Y=[-1,1], we are DONE.
Sorry, but your solution isn't very understandable.

Comment: @Mathematicing no, maybe this is the problem: The open ball $\left\{y:y\in Y, d(\frac 1 2,y)<\varepsilon\right\}$ around an $x\in X$ **needs** to be a subset of $Y$, and not of $X$. Here is what I've done in a nutshell: We want to show $X$ is not open in $Y$, for this we find an open ball around $\frac 12\in X$, this open ball is a subset of $Y$ but for no radius ($\varepsilon$) a subset (contained) in $X$, therefore $X$ is not open.

Comment: @Mathematicing In my experience the argument and set theoretic definitions that user190080 has used in the answer provided are very standard for a question of this variety. There are many alternate definitions for the topological properties being discussed here.

Answer (score 0):

Y=[-1,1]  which is closed subset of reals...
Let X ={x|1/2<=|x|<1} 
or we can say 
X=(-1,-1/2] union [1/2,1)
It is neither open nor closed....
Complement of X in Y is the same as given in the question....i.e. (-1/2,1/2)union {-1} union{1}……
Now complement is not open as it is not the nbd. of -1 and 1.....or we can say -1 and 1 are not interior points of complement of X.....hence X cannot be closed....
X is not open as....-1/2 and 1/2 are not interior points of X.....
Hence X is neither open nor closed......
(For interior points there should exist at least one nbd. of radius epsilon which is contained in that set.....)